# Unable to understand transition from one equation to another in linear regression. (From Ch-2, The elements of Statistical Learning)

Tags: machine-learning, math, statistics, linear-regression

While reading linear regression in Ch-2 of book "The elements of Statistical Learning", I came across 2 equations and I failed to understand how the 2nd was derived from the first.

Background:

How do we fit the linear model to a set of training data? There are
many different methods, but by far the most popular is the method of
least squares. In this approach, we pick the coefficients β to minimize the
residual sum of squares

Equation 1

RSS(β) is a quadratic function of the parameters, and hence its minimum
always exists, but may not be unique. The solution is easiest to characterize
in matrix notation. We can write

Equation 2

where X is an N × p matrix with each row an input vector, and y is an
N-vector of the outputs in the training set.

1st equation:

[image]

2nd equation:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The RHS of the 2nd equation is in the matrix form and to get the 1st equation, you have to transpose one part of the RHS of 2nd equation(this is how matrix multiplication is done)